# Is there ARcore support for the Oneplus 6

Tags: android, game-development, arcore

Does anyone know when the oneplus 6 will get support for ARcore or if there is any way to get ARcore support for the oneplus 6 right now?. I heard someone on a oneplus forum say that it will work if you are running the android p beta but it hasn't seemed to work for me yet.

Comment: This is current list of supported devices/os versions https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices

Comment: Um yeah, I saw that list already I was just wondering if someone can answer when? Cause I'm thinking of developing AR apps in the near future and the one plus 6 is a really good bang for the buck phone, so I'm wondering if the one plus 6 will work?

Answer (score 0):

ARCore is now enabled for OnePlus 6 in Google Play (am on Oxygen OS v5.1.8)